# How can I guess which software produces a sound?

Tags: windows, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What process is making that sound?](https://superuser.com/questions/138002/what-process-is-making-that-sound)

Using Windows, is there any solution to know which software produces an annoying sound ?

Comment: Any specific version of Windows?

Comment: What kind of sound?  How often does it happen?  Are you able to record it so we can hear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever sound is being played is seen in volume mixer under windows .It is on right side of taskbar...
[image: volume mixer1]

[image: volume mixer]

**it will turn bar green** if any activity of app is **playing** some sound...
[image: sound being played]

here  app **spotify is rendering sound with max volume**.. as you can see bar has turned green

This will easily tell you which app is annoying you with sounds.....

Comment: This is probably the only app where you might catch this, but if the sound is coming from a program running in the background/system tray then it is likely to either not show up or to show just under "System Sounds", which won't help you locate it.